# All Network from fixed distance of a point

Tags: arcgis-desktop, network-analyst

I am new to Network Analyst.

I have a network dataset and I want to generate all polylines (streets) calculated from a single origin (point) with a fixed distance (non-euclidean).

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  I recommend not thinking about GIS SE as being some sort of online GIS tutor.  For your questions to be answered here they should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that.

Answer (score 2):

This can be achieved using a Service Area solver of Network Analyst. You would need to:

1. Use length of your network edges as [impedance](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/extensions/network-analyst/understanding-network-attributes.htm) (i.e., cost).
2. Set the option [Generate Lines](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/extensions/network-analyst/service-area.htm) to create lines traversing all streets that are reachable within a certain impedance (in your case, distance) value.